# How to call button click event using Normal method in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a method name loadTest123(). I tried to call Button1_Click event from loadTest123(). But event not occurred. I am trying to debug with break point in Button1_Click event but not triggering.

**E.g:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadTest123();
        }

        public Button Coke = new Button();

        public void loadTest123()
        {
            Coke.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Hello!!!");      
        }        
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

what you have done is just binding of event, you have not called it.
You have to call that event to actually run it.

Do this,

```
button1.PerformClick();
```

OR,

```
button1_Click(null, new EventArgs());
```

in your method.

Comment: updated the code....please see that. I am facing same problem. I put break point in Button1_Click but event not triggering.

Comment: can you show me your updated code? want to see what you are passing as param.

Comment: Call with null and new EventArgs() :
button1_click(null, new EventArgs()) in your load function

Comment: public Button Coke = new Button();

        public void loadTest123()
        {
            Coke.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Hello!!!");      
        }

Comment: just write button1_Click(null, new EventArgs());

Comment: button1.PerformClick() is more sexier.

Comment: I have a question : Why do you create a button to do this? I see your button is instanciated in your class but never added into your Form, so your button will not be display on your form.

Comment: lol thanks. and let's take that one step further then ;-) passing null is not entirely correct better would be button1_Click(button1,new EventArgs())

Comment: Please stop bothering users to upvote and accept your solutions. That is not what comments are for.

Answer (score 1):

What you have in `loadTest123()` method is for subscribing to an event, it won't trigger subscribed method until you perform **click** on it.

Also, you have attached `button1_Click` to `Click` event but there is no method declared with the name. You need (something) like this.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         MessageBox.Show("Hello!!!");      
   }
```

If you are looking to perform click *programatically*, there is a `PerfromClick` method on button, you could use it.

```
Coke.PerformClick();
```

*You created the button but not added to controls, is this intentional?*

Answer (score 0):

see below code and comments

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    loadTest123();
}

public Button Coke = new Button();

public void loadTest123()
{
    // BELOW LINE IS ONLY FOR REGISTER YOUR BUTTON'S CLICK EVENT
    Coke.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);

    // FIRE YOUR EVENT IN CODE BEHIND
    Coke.PerformClick();
    // OR
    button1_Click(null, new EventArgs());
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Hello!!!");      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
InvokeOnClick(button, e);
```